# how to know which menuitem is clicked using wh_getmessage hook?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hook

i want to know which menuitem is clicked using WH_GETMESSAGE hook.can somebody help me please...from one week i stuck with this problem?
plz provide a way how can we achive this..using win32 dll. i am working on vc++6.0.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The "flag for moderator" is for administrative support, not answers.

Answer (score 0):

With `WH_GETMESSAGE` you can monitor any message.

When you catch [WM_MENUSELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646352(VS.85).aspx) you can examine the `wParam` to get the id/index.

Answer (score 0):

from MSDN..

> WM_MENUSELECT
>
> **wParam**
>
> The low-order word specifies
> the menu item or submenu index. If the
> selected item is a command item, this
> parameter contains the identifier of
> the menu item.
>
> If the selected item
> opens a drop-down menu or submenu,
> this parameter contains the index of
> the drop-down menu or submenu in the
> main menu, and the lParam parameter
> contains the handle to the main
> (clicked) menu; use the GetSubMenu
> function to get the menu handle to the
> drop-down menu or submenu.

once you had the menu handle, you can always do GetMenuItemInfo / GetMenuItemID / GetMenuInfo etc...